# Mixing webGL(ThreeJS) with regular HTML/CSS website

Tags: json, html, css, three.js, webgl

I currently have an animated image as the background of a website with HTML elements in front of it.  Is it possible to replace that image with JSON geometry and still have my html elements in front of the geometry?

I've (unsuccessfully) looked into DOM Elements in ThreeJS.  Tried putting my JSON in a div and controlling it with CSS..... That being said - is it possible to "style" or add JSON/js to a css?

Thanks to anyone that can help!!!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: If you have the JSON loading in a THREE.js scene, then you're almost there. Just put the `renderer.domElement` (an HTML5 canvas element) in place of your animated background image. Note that you may need to add a window resize handler to update the size and aspect ratio of your renderer, because it won't handle that automatically like and image would.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can position the element you introduce that will contain your scene absolutely, stretch it across the screen and then add the rest of your elements in the DOM:

```
.scene {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

If you place it as the first child in the body, it will ensure that the rest of the content has a higher `z-index`, otherwise you will manually have to assign the value to the elements to ensure the scene isn't obfuscating the content.

Since the scene element will adjust to the screen size, you'll have to keep track when window resizes and ensure you update the scene dimensions with it, as one of the commenters pointed out.

Comment: My scene running in the background https://github.com/langri-sha/langri-sha.github.io/blob/gh-pages/src/index.js#L25

Comment: Thanks for your help! Position: absolute; makes sense.  That's how I was able to get the image in the back ground originally.  However, adding that property to a div with my "GearBackground.js" script only places it on top of the content.  Here is my "workshop" project I'm working on to teach my self this.  Is there something in there that would be preventing that property from working? http://ab3d.work/

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have that content available during my original post......

Comment: Posting prematurely but super excited!!!! I realized that my <div>script src "3d.js" </div> was creating a canvas containing the script in browser.  I added your styling suggestions to the canvas element and it appears to be working!!!  Thank you for your recommendation! Moving forward. while toying around, visual studio it telling me I can't add a script tag to canvas.  It runs but creates a 2nd canvas tag in browser containing the 3d and pushes it parent aside.  Any idea why it does this?